# Flutter store users data with Cloud Firestore and Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a collection of "Users" in **Cloud Firestore** and I am using **Firebase Auth** to authenticate my app users as follows:

1. The user authenticates within the mobile app (for example with Google).
2. I verify that there is no document within the "Users" collection that corresponds to the UID of the authenticated user.
3. If the document does not exist in "Users" I use the user's UID to create a new document.

**It is my question:** *Is there a security problem with this model or some other type?*

I am confused by Google documentation because it says that the user's UID is unique to the Firebase project but should not be used to authenticate my user to the backend server. It also says that in that case, I should use FirebaseUser.getToken () but that token can change, so it will create a new user in my DB.

So, **my second question is:** When should you use that token? Give me an example, please.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you please indicate the official documentation where you read that the UID "should not be used to authenticate my user to the backend server"?

Comment: Sure, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users ... It is inside the code of getting a user profile like a comment

Answer (score 1):

**USER_ID**

You can use the google generated user_id for future reference. That will never change for a given user email or authentication type as long as the user is already in the database.

Example:
If the user Signed In with google federated login with user1@example.com then the user record is maintained in the Firebase and USER_ID(Say `ABFDe12cdaa2...`) will be assigned(You can use this id in URLs to see the user profile etc it is kind of 32 chars long(I am not sure exactly here). Now, If a user tries to sign up again with the same email(user1@example.com) then it pulls the previous record `ABFDe12cdaa2...`. If you delete a user1@example.com from the firebase database(Firebase maintains its own database of the user for your project, With has a limited number of user properties). Then the user tries to sign in again then the new USER_ID is generated.

Now the **TOKEN**:

As you USER_ID is public, it can be seen by everyone. It is not used for authentication.

So you need to generate the token( This is longer the user id) to authenticate programmatically with the Firebase. It token is temporary and specific to the user. It will expire in some time ( you can define that time while creating the token). a refresh token is used to get a new token.

I don't have any code examples while writing this answer. I will update with code example,If, I find any.

Hope I clarified some of your questions.

Comment: @LucasPatiño does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I understood the difference, but I'm not sure if there is a security issue with the way I'm saving users.

Comment: You haven't told me how you are saying. It is usual to save the extra attribute if the user-specific to your app in the firestore collection. But you need to guard the access using security rules. If you can share your rules we can tell.

Comment: @nagabandaru The way I save users is in the initial question. There you find it by steps as I am doing.